# In respect to the delay caused today

Tags: grammar

> *In **respect** to the delay caused today, we will email notice in future.*

What does the meaning of "in respect"?

Comment: You will find this in most dictionaries. Here's [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/respect?showCookiePolicy=true); you want #4.

Comment: But then it suggests *with respect to/in respect of*... or the rule is loose? @StoneyB

Comment: @Maulik Yes, *With respect to* would be better. But few people make these careful distinctions any more, so you have to get used to the sloppy versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a way of saying that due to the delay/in light of the delay caused today, [...].

You could also say:

> Considering the delay caused today, we will email notice you in
>   future.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly "In respect to" is bad. "with respect to" is better but it really doesn't convey the meaning I believe the author intended. Normally you'd use this phrase to give context to the main clause of the sentence.
Eg

> With respect to exam results, I shall be posting something on the noticeboard this afternoon.

It still a bit clumsy but gives you an example.

For the actual sentence you provided it may be written:

> Due to the disruption caused by recent delays we shall email notice of future periods of downtime.

or even:

> ### Service disruption
>
> Sorry about recent delays. We shall email you notice of downtime in future.

I have, of course, inferred some extra meaning as to what the delays were about.